# Dual VGA Cards Intel/ Nvidia

Tags: server, drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus

This is my first post in this forum. I am new to Linux, just installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my Sony Vaio VGN-Z12 with two graphic cards Intel and NVidia Geforce 9300 GS.

After the installation the lightdm works on Intel card but with very law display quality. I installed Nvidia driver from the official website as well as this PPA.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Once I installed the driver and run nvidia-xconfig which creates xorg.conf file, the xserver will not start with error "no screen". If I delete the xorg.conf file then I am able to start the xserver normally but with intel display (bad quality)

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu. Check out the link: http://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work. Installing multiple drivers for one device is a bad idea. ...and remember the golden rule, 'search before asking'.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I did a lot of search before asking this question but couldn't find a proper solution.. I tried to install Bumblebee as suggested by the link but still the Nvidia card is not active. from system information it shows unknown graphic card & fallback experience. I don't want to use the VGA swapping option, I am interested only to use my NVidia card to have a better display quality..

Comment: any help on this is really appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have Nvidia Optimus technology in your laptop, you have, according to the [Project Bumblebee FAQ](https://github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/wiki/FAQ), two options:

1) Check your system bios for an option to permanently switch to your nvidia graphics card (make sure you uninstall bumblebee before doing that!)

2) If your bios does not provide this feature you can't just run your nvidia card. What can do is starting single applications directly with your nvidia graphics card from a terminal console with

> optirun [yourappofchoice]

Does this help?