# Second graphics card

Tags: nvidia, xorg, hybrid-graphics

I have two graphics card in my laptop.

[image]

However, I am unable to activate the NVIDIA one. I need to use it, because the integrated Intel card can't connect through DVI/HDMI.

I have the drivers installed, however I am unable to "select" the NVIDIA card.

[image]

How do I enable the second graphics card?

[image]

While running as suggested gives

```
sudo: nvidia-xconfig: command not found
```

Trying to install `nvidia-xconfig` fails as there's no such package.

Comment: you might find the solution here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/121856/dual-vga-cards-intel-nvidia/123294#123294

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would give Bumblebee a try, although HDMI ports are a bit of a hit-and-miss sometimes:
[Is a NVIDIA GeForce with Optimus Technology supported by Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36930/how-well-do-laptops-with-nvidia-optimus-work/36936#36936)

Comment: Well I installed it and it enables me to run applications using the `optirun` command. What I was looking for is to be able to connect to external monitors using VGA or HDMI. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Many laptops have the ability to do that, since most of the displaying work is carried by the Intel card, whereas the Nvidia card just does some computations and hands over the results to the Intel card. But there have been cases of problems with HDMI ports in hybrid-graphics laptops.

Comment: I forgot to mention that if you haven't done yet, it would be useful to submit your DSDT information as explained in this website: http://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux