# Ubuntu 11.04 Bumblebee package not found

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee

The official nvidia drivers are not working properly on my thinkpad T520 So I was going to give bumblebee a shot.

I have an ubuntu 11.04 install and am reciving a package not found error when trying to install bumblebee. I followed the instructions on the bumblebe site. It did work on my 12.10 install but not on my 11.04. the error I am receiving is

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package bumblebee
E: Unable to locate package bumblebee-nvidia
```

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide *all* the commands you issued? I mean, you first added the repository, right? Can you add the commands you used for that? Can you also check your software sources? Can you check whether the repository is online? Can you check whether your `sudo apt-get update` was successful or showed errors?

Comment: 11.04 is End of Life, and as such you should upgrade to 12.04 or another supported release.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this is old, but here is my (anti climactic) answer.

As earlier stated...

> 11.04 is End of Life, and as such you should upgrade to 12.04 or another supported release. –  Thomas W.

So that is exactly what I did. Bumblebee works fine in 12.04.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia linux-headers-generic
Reboot or re-login
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response. still no dice, same error as earlier.

Comment: try these 
    `sudo apt-add-repository ppa:mj-casalogic/bumblebee`
    `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install bumblebee` and reboot

Comment: still same error, if it is any help, I am getting a few 404s when i  run update. Sorry having a tough time posting the error in the comment. one of the 404s is "http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources " could this be causing the issue?

Comment: one solution is open your sources.list using `gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list` remove the lines containing PPA like 
`deb http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net natty/main Sources` and then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: gave it a shot, once I removed the ppa items, and ran the update/upgrade a bunch of ppa related things 404'd

Comment: So, the problem should be sources.list file, try removing or unabling (add `#` in the start of the line) the lines which appear as 404 not found, then update and try installing Bumblebee again

Comment: post your `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MuX2NFHQ thats my sources.list. the ppa ones dont seem to be in the list, they give a "W: Failed ot fetch" 404 error which is slightly different from the other 404 errors I was receiving.

Comment: @WhileHungryEatSandwich did you try Rodrigo Martins solution??

Comment: yes, the ppa sources are not in the list, yet they still show up as 404 on an update. I did comment out the ones that were there though.

here is the exact output I am gettin on an update http://pastebin.com/Z72DNx0g

Comment: can you show which all ppa that show as 404 on an update??

Comment: You can find the other ppas in Software Sources program, then it's just to go to `Other programs` tab and uncheck the ppas that returns errors.

Comment: ah okay I just unchecked them, most of them were related to bumblebee, I also figured out chat, so you can reach me there too.

Comment: I am user15936 :)

Answer (score 0):

Before installing Bumblebee you need to add [its repository](https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee/+archive/stable) and [more one](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-x-swat/+archive/x-updates) that will enable Ubuntu 11.04 and older versions to install newer drivers. So type the following in the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:bumblebee/stable
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
```

([Click here for instructions on using PPAs.](https://askubuntu.com/q/4983))

Now you will be able to install Bumblebee:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia
```

If problem persists maybe some ppas that you've added to your system is preventing apt-get to update your system and to get the programs of recently added ppas.

Open your `sources.list`:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Then delete lines from ppas that return 404 when updating. Some of the ppas may not be listed in `sources.list`, then open Software Sources, go to `Other Programs` tab and disable the ppas that are giving errors.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so fast, sadly still receiving the same error.

Comment: Maybe the second repository is broken, try to remove it: `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates`, then update `sudo apt-get update` and try to install Bumblebee `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia`

Comment: same error, I am getting a bunch of 404s when I run apt-get update. Could that be part of the issue?

Comment: Can you install any other package? Maybe your `sources.list` is broken.

Comment: yes, I have installed many things without problem. bumblebee seems to be the only issue I have run into so far.

Comment: As the second repository wasn't the problem add it again, run `sudo apt-get update`, and then perform in the terminal: `sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia -y`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/6906/discussion-between-rodrigo-martins-and-whilehungryeatsandwich)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Bumblebee Projects PPA Page](https://launchpad.net/~bumblebee/+archive/stable), Bumblebee ist only supported for Ubuntu 12.04 and newer. For full dual-gpu-support you should install a newer version of ubuntu than 11.04 or the current version of Ubuntu (13.04).

After running a 12.04 Ubuntu or newer, installing your Nvidia card and Bumblebee works with this [manual](https://askubuntu.com/questions/121856/dual-vga-cards-intel-nvidia/123294#123294) or the previously mentioned manuals. I hope I could help.